# Binary Insertion Sort in a similar fashion of regular Insertion Sort

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

So I'm trying to figure out how to properly use Binary Insertion Sort without the need for a swap method or anything like that. A friend of mine gave me a rough interpretation of the necessary code but I can't seem to get it to do as I want.

```
private static int binaryInsertionSort(int[] b)
{
    int left, right, middle, i, m;
    int compareCount = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < b.length; j++)
    {
        left = b[j - 1];
        right = b[j + 1];
        if (b[j] < b[left])
        {
            i = left;
        }
        else
        {
            i = left + 1;
        }
        m = b[j];
        for(int k = 0; k < (j - i - 1); k++)
        {
            b[j - k] = b[j - k - 1];
            compareCount++;
        }
        b[i] = m;
    }
    return compareCount;
}
```

The int compareCount is merely just to see how many comparisons are carried out over the course of the method. Now what I'm trying to do is arrange an array of integers in regular fashion, specifically like b[0] = 1, b[1] = 2,...... b[63] = 64. In my main method i create the array and assign values in the reverse: b[0] = 64, b[1] = 63, etc. How can I get this code to rearrange them into the normal fashion I seek? I was able to do this very simply with normal insertion sort, but this is a little more......... tricky to me.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. After much tinkering and figuring out specific details with another friend, we've managed to find out exactly how to do this.

```
public static int binaryInsertionSort(int[] b)
{
    int lo, mid, hi, temp;
    int compareCount = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < b.length; i++) 
    {
        lo = 0; 
        hi = i;
        mid = i / 2;
        do 
        {
            if (b[i] > b[mid]) 
            {
                lo = mid + 1;
                compareCount++;
            } 
            else if (b[i] < b[mid]) 
            {
                hi = mid;
                compareCount++;
            } 
            else
            {
                compareCount++;
                break;
            }
            mid = lo + ((hi - lo) / 2);
        } while (lo < hi);
        if (mid < i) 
        {
            temp = b[i];
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= mid; j--)
            {
                b[j + 1] = b[j];
                compareCount++;
            }
            b[mid] = temp;
        }
    }
    return compareCount;
}
```

Very tricky indeed, but with effort comes rewards. Regardless that no one answered, I still thank those who viewed my question.